# Delete similar items that start the same from a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

For example, I have this list:

```
list = ["192.168.1.1", "0.1.2.3", "0.2.3.4", "192.168.1.2", "0.3.4.5", "192.168.1.3"]
```

How can I remove with a command all the items that start with `"0."`?

Comment: Note that `[192.168.1.1, 0.1.2.3, 0.2.3.4, 192.168.1.2, 0.3.4.5, 192.168.1.3]` is not a valid list declaration. You have to put your values in `"` or `'`.

Comment: yeah that's my fault.... just updated it

Comment: It's frowned upon to name your objects using reserved words, as it'll mask the original meaning (e.g., don't call your `list` list).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can filter the desired items in a list using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) using [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) to check if a string starts with "0.":

```
>>> l = ['192.168.1.1', '0.1.2.3', '1.2.3.4', '192.168.1.2', '0.3.4.5', '192.168.1.3']
>>> [item for item in l if not item.startswith('0.')]
['192.168.1.1', '1.2.3.4', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3']
```

Note that `list` is not a good variable name - it *[shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the built-in `list`*.

---

You can also approach the problem with [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and a filtering function:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith("0."), l))
['192.168.1.1', '1.2.3.4', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3']
```

Note that in Python 3.x, unlike Python 2.x, `filter()` returns an *iterator*, hence, calling `list()` to demonstrate the result.

---

And, a "just for fun" option and to demonstrate how can you overcomplicate the problem with different functional programming-style tools:

```
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> from itertools import filterfalse
>>>
>>> list(filterfalse(methodcaller('startswith', "0."), l))
['192.168.1.1', '1.2.3.4', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3']
```

[`itertools.filterfalse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) and [`operator.methodcaller()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) were used.

Comment: filter() works always and startswith() sometimes yes e sometimes not

Answer (score 1):

With `filter()`:

```
lst = ["192.168.1.1", "0.1.2.3", "0.2.3.4", "192.168.1.2", "0.3.4.5, 192.168.1.3"]
new_lst = list(filter(lambda x: x if not x.startswith("0") else None, lst))
print(new_lst)
```

Comment: this method has worked... filter() works always and startswith() sometimes yes e sometimes not... so thanks!